# Updating deeply nested fields that are immutable

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a heavily nested class structure that does not have setters.

```
@Value
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class ClassA {
    private String fieldA;
    private ClassB classB;
}

@Value
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class ClassB {
    private ClassC classC;
    private ClassD classD;
}

@Value
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class ClassC {
    private ClassE classE;
}


@Value
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class ClassD {
    private String fieldD;
}


@Value
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class ClassE {
    private String fieldE;
}
```

@Value comes from Lombok which sets all the fields to private finals. Since there are no setters and if I need to update fieldE, I need to update parent objects as well and it would like something like this:

```
classA = classA.toBuilder()
            .classB(classA.getClassB().toBuilder()
                .classD(classA.getClassB().getClassD().toBuilder()
                    .fieldD("abc")
                    .build())
                .build())
            .build();
```

Some of the fields that I need to update are about 8 levels deep and incase I need to check for nulls, the code can get quite messy.

I cannot modify the original POJOs and make them mutable. Is there a different approach I can do to make this easier to update fields? I thought of using the facade pattern, but I guess with that approach, I'll need to recreate the whole class hierarchy again. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a well-known problem in functional programming, and usually addressed with so-called *lenses*. I don't have time right now, but I may be able to write a C#-overview later, if you're interested. I don't know, however, how well that would translate to Java, and that particular framework.

Comment: @MarkSeemann thanks for the reply. Would appreciate a sample when you get the chance to see if I can understand the pattern and try to apply it in Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Mark Seemann, this problem can kind of be solved with lenses.

The idea is that a `Lens<A, B>` represents a way to get a `B` from an instance of `A`, and a way to set a new `B` for an instance of `A`. Each field of your classes can then be represented by a lens.

You can compose lenses. If you have a `Lens<A, B>`, and a `Lens<B, C>`, you can compose them to get `Lens<A, C>`. This is the key to setting a deeply nested field. You just need to compose lots of lenses together, then call `set` on that final composed lens.

```
ClassA modifiedClassA = ClassA.CLASS_B_LENS
        .then(ClassB.CLASS_D_LENS) // I've called the composition operation "then"
        .then(ClassD.FIELD_D_LENS)
        .set(someClassA, "New Value!");
```

Here is a possible implementation.

```
interface Lens<Root, T> {
    T get(Root r);
    // here I generalised the set operation to a "modify",
    // where the previous value is also available
    Root modify(Root root, UnaryOperator<T> newValue);

    default Root set(Root root, T newValue) {
        return modify(root, x -> newValue);
    }

    default <U> Lens<Root, U> then(Lens<T, U> p2) {
        return new Lens<>() {
            @Override
            public U get(Root r) {
                return p2.get(Lens.this.get(r));
            }

            @Override
            public Root modify(Root r, UnaryOperator<U> f) {
                return Lens.this.modify(r, t -> p2.modify(Lens.this.get(r), f));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

You can then make a factory method like this to create lenses from a getter and a "wither". The latter can be generated by the lombok [`@With`](https://projectlombok.org/features/With) annotation. You can put all the null checks in this factory.

```
static <Root, T> Lens<Root, T> make(Function<Root, T> getter, BiFunction<Root, T, Root> setter) {
    return new Lens<>() {
        @Override
        public T get(Root r) {
            if (r == null) return null;
            return getter.apply(r);
        }

        @Override
        public Root modify(Root root, UnaryOperator<T> f) {
            if (root == null) return null;
            return setter.apply(root, f.apply(get(root)));
        }
    };
}
```

You can then add some lenses to your classes as static fields. This part can be done by a code generator/annotation processor, if you know how to write one.

```
@Value
@With
class ClassA {
    private String fieldA;
    private ClassB classB;

    public static final Lens<ClassA, String> FIELD_A_LENS = Lens.make(ClassA::getFieldA, ClassA::withFieldA);
    public static final Lens<ClassA, ClassB> CLASS_B_LENS = Lens.make(ClassA::getClassB, ClassA::withClassB);
}

@Value
@With
class ClassB {
    private ClassC classC;
    private ClassD classD;

    public static final Lens<ClassB, ClassC> CLASS_C_LENS = Lens.make(ClassB::getClassC, ClassB::withClassC);
    public static final Lens<ClassB, ClassD> CLASS_D_LENS = Lens.make(ClassB::getClassD, ClassB::withClassD);
}

// and so on...
```

See also [this medium article](https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/lenses-in-java-2b18c7d24366) that takes a slightly different approach.

Comment: @Sweepr Thank you so much. This is a really interest pattern and thanks for sharing this approach. I wasn't able to figure out how do I go about updating a list or a collection with this approach though. Do you've any thoughts around it?

Comment: @user1692342 I assume the collections are also immutable? You can get a lens that refers to the collection, and do `someLens.modify(someObj, x -> x.add(y))` to add a new thing `y` to the collection, assuming `add` returns a new collection with the new element added.

Comment: Very good answer, love from London